# lucia-auth mongoose typescript syntax is incorrect lucia.ts

Tags: typescript, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am very new to TypeScript and to lucia-auth. I was following the documentation's instructions for the Mongoose database adapter, and in the lucia.ts file, I am getting red underlines in VSCode for each 'Model', as well as with 'InitializeAdapter'.

For 'Model', it says "

Here is my code:

```
import { mongoose } from "@lucia-auth/adapter-mongoose";
// Imported the correct module

const mongoose: (models: {
    User: Model;
    Session: Model | null;
    Key: Model;
}) => InitializeAdapter<Adapter>;
```

I've read about this error being fixed by providing a value for the const, but I am unsure how to do that for this specific piece of code without messing it up.

If anyone could provide some advice or pointers on how to solve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't waste your time with this package. I've been on their discord channel for 2 days trying to solve the same issue. All they post is a link to sveltekit example which has an example to sqlite??? How is that related to mongodb and mongoose,???   If one person posts the code for mongodb and mongoose on discord, it would be a huge help for the community. Not a link to an example with sqlite adapter.

Comment: I concur. I just used express-session and connect-mongo instead.